# Concatenate two GSUtil Command

Tags: concatenation, gsutil

I want to execute two gsutil command in a single line, how can i achieve that.
For ex:

```
gsutil ls gs://projectname/bucketname/folder1/folder2/filename.png | \
 cp gs://projectname/bucketname/folder3/folder4/
```

Find/ List a file from specific bucket and copy the same file to the bucket folder. In the above command i'm using ls (list) and cp (copy) command, but this is not working as expected.

Something similar to the below shell script or linux command, we use exec and continue the next command right.

`find -type f -path '*schedule*/*' -name "*.png" -exec cp -n {} /tmp/MusicFiles \;`

Your early response is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner: From `gsutil help cp`:

```
  -I             Causes gsutil to read the list of files or objects to copy from
                 stdin. This allows you to run a program that generates the list
                 of files to upload/download.
```

So, `some_program | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket`.

Where some program can be `gsutil ls ...`

Additionally,

gsutil accepts [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames), so that command would be something like this.

```
gsutul cp gs:/bucket-name/*schedule*/*/*.png gs://bucketname/folder3/folder4/
```

Notice that there it is possible to do single star `*` and double star `**` for recursive wildcards.

Comment: you can also use the `gsutil -m cp to` to do the copy in parallel.

Comment: i wanted to concatenate two gsutil commands in single line, like list a file and copy the same file using ls and cp command in a line.